# Repeat and concatenate a DataFrame with constant step value increase

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following example:

```
   A  B  C   D   E   F
0  1  4  7  10  13  16
1  2  5  8  11  14  17
2  3  6  9  12  15  18
```

I want to repeat the all dataframe like it was one block,
like I want to repeat the above dataframe 3 times and every element increases by 3 than the original one.

The desired dataframe:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  1   4   7  10  13  16
1  2   5   8  11  14  17
2  3   6   9  12  15  18
3  4   7  10  13  16  19
4  5   8  11  14  17  20
5  6   9  12  15  18  21
6  7  10  14  16  19  22
7  8  11  15  17  20  23
8  9  12  16  18  21  24
```

My real df is like:

```
         0   1   2   3   4   5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
11  CONECT  12   9  13                             
12  CONECT  13  12  14  15  16                     
13  CONECT  14  13                                 
14  CONECT  15  13                                 
15  CONECT  16  13  17  18  19                     
16  CONECT  17  16
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('connect_part.txt',  'sample_file.csv', names =['A'])
df = df.A.str.split(expand=True)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
repeats = 3
step = 3
df1 = df.set_index([0]) # add all non-numeric columns here
df2 = pd.concat([df1+i for i in range(0, len(df1)*repeats, step)]).reset_index()
print(df2)
```

error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: It was just an example to show my problem (not real data frame)

Comment: have you had a chance to test if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71631310/16343464) works?

Answer (score 2):

```
res = pd.concat([df + 3*i for i in range(3)], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  1   4   7  10  13  16
1  2   5   8  11  14  17
2  3   6   9  12  15  18
3  4   7  10  13  16  19
4  5   8  11  14  17  20
5  6   9  12  15  18  21
6  7  10  13  16  19  22
7  8  11  14  17  20  23
8  9  12  15  18  21  24
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9],
    'D': [10, 11, 12],
    'E': [13, 14, 15],
    'F': [16, 17, 18]
})
```

Comment: Virtually the same as my answer

Comment: @mozway Similar but simpler

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` as input, use `pandas.concat`:

```
repeats = 3
step = 3
df2 = pd.concat([df+i for i in range(0, len(df)*repeats, step)],
                ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  1   4   7  10  13  16
1  2   5   8  11  14  17
2  3   6   9  12  15  18
3  4   7  10  13  16  19
4  5   8  11  14  17  20
5  6   9  12  15  18  21
6  7  10  13  16  19  22
7  8  11  14  17  20  23
8  9  12  15  18  21  24
```

###### update: non-numeric columns:

```
repeats = 3
step = 3

df1 = df.set_index([0]) # add all non-numeric columns here

df2 = pd.concat([df1+i for i in range(0, len(df1)*repeats, step)]).reset_index()
```

Comment: It gives me this error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"  as my df has int and str

Comment: @Elsaid can you update your question to provide python code to instantiate a representative example `DataFrame`

Comment: Done man, please check!

Comment: It is just in a text file

Comment: @Elsaid you can set the non-numeric columns as index, try the update (make sure all other columns **are numeric**)

Comment: 'code'
df1.set_index(0)
df1.fillna('', inplace=True)

repeats = 3
step = 3
df2 = pd.concat([df+i for i in range(0, len(df)*repeats, step)],
                ignore_index=True)
'code'  gives the same error

Comment: But this code is working in a similar data frame:dfe = pd.concat([dfe1]*400, ignore_index=True)
print(dfe)
 why?

Comment: It worked for me using the text you provided. Please provide a DataFrame constructor to avoid any ambiguity

Comment: Can you please check the question update?

Comment: @Elsaid unfortunately, using `read_csv` with files that I don't have makes it non reproducible :(

Comment: the file 'connect_part.txt' contains the real df(just copy and paste)